# Where are layout handles defined by a module?

Tags: magento2, layout, xml

I want to find all of the handles available for a module whether they are in `vendor/magento/module/view/layouts/...` or not.

What is the **best way to see all of the handles that can be used for a module**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me, the layout related to each module can be found directly in the module `view/layouts` folder

However, if you have a doubt I suggest you do the following.

- Find the route name of your module in the `routes.xml` e.g. `catalog`
- Run the following command from your Magento 2 directory: `find . -type f -name 'catalog_*.xml'` (replace `catalog` with the route you just found)

It will give you a list of every layout file related to the route you specified and thus you can have a list of handles.

Answer (score 0):

You can check module's all handle under **`view`** folder of your module.

Just for **Catalog** Module of core systm,.
You can see handle under below location.

Some module have **base** folder under view directory those also contains handle realted to module.
 `vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/base/layout` ,

For **frontend** handle are under `vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/layout` folder.

For **admin** handle are under `vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/adminhtml/layout` folder.

Thanks.

Comment: catalog_category_view.xml
catalog_category_view_type_default.xml
catalog_category_view_type_default_without_children.xml
catalog_product_compare_index.xml
catalog_product_gallery.xml
catalog_product_opengraph.xml
catalog_product_view.xml
catalog_product_view_type_simple.xml
catalog_product_view_type_virtual.xml
checkout_cart_item_renderers.xml
default.xml

In frontend I can only see these files yet there are more handles available for catalogue - what gives?

Comment: for catalog there are many product types are available, ex, config,simple,bundle,downloadable and each product type have separate module so you have to look for Magento_Downloadble, Magento_Bundle, Magento_Configurable module

Comment: I think you are mistaken. There are catalog_category_view_id_<id>.xml layout handles available, yet they cannot be found easily without viewing the PHP code?

Answer (score 0):

Handler  for a module can be available at

- `vendor/magento/[Module-ComposerName]/view/layouts/`
- `app/design/[DesignArea]/[PackageName or VendorName]/[Theme]/[VendorName]_[ModuleName]/layout/`
- `vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/[VendorName]_[ModuleName]/layout`

**For 3rd part module,it can be  find at**

*`app/code/[VendorName]/[ModuleName]/view/layout/`*